# Sqlite with FTS on Windows Phone

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7, full-text-search

I'm fairly ignorant wrt sqlite, but from what I've found out there appear to be two main implementations for windows phone that folks here are using:

1. [C# Sqlite for WP7](http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/)
2. [Sqlite Client for Windows Phone](http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/)

Is there a pros/cons list of these two projects somewhere?

I also haven't seen anything stating that full text search is supported on the WP implementation of any of these. Does anyone know any different? This is a key requirement for my business (and I'm willing to help push to get) and we can't go ahead with our WP implementation of our product until we have this.

If these projects are ported from the core sqlite source code, is it just a matter of defining `SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3` in the projects and recompiling to [enable it](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_2)?

Answer (score 0):

WP7 is a "sandboxed" environment, that said, no native code (c++, pinvoke) is allowed. Those porting are not based on external libraries, they are written with fully managed code (only c#) so in practice it is "not just matter of defining SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3".

As far as I know, the only solution that implements FTS is Perst http://www.mcobject.com/perst. You can try it out and check if it fits to your needs, as is open source for non commercial projects. Unfortunatelly for commercial purpose, you need to buy a paid license.

I'm facing the same problematic, let me know if you find any valid clue.